# Pandas: complex condition on datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a dataframe with a datetime type column and a float type column.

```
                     date  value
0     2010-01-01 01:23:00  21.2
1     2010-01-02 01:33:00  63.4
2     2010-01-03 06:02:00  80.6
3     2010-01-04 06:05:00  50.1
4     2010-01-05 06:20:00  346.5
5     2010-01-06 07:44:00  111.8
6     2010-01-07 08:00:00  113.1
7     2010-01-08 08:22:00  10.6
8     2010-01-09 09:00:00  287.2
9     2010-01-10 09:14:00  1652.6
```

I want to create a new column to record the mean value of one hours before the current iteration row time.

**[UPDATE] Example**:

If the current iteration is `4 2010-01-05 06:20:00  346.5` , I need to calculate `(50.1 + 80.6) / 2` (value in range `2010-01-05 05:20:00~2010-01-05 06:20:00` and calculate mean).

```
                     date  value  before_1hr_mean
4     2010-01-05 06:20:00  346.5  65.35
```

I use `iterrows()` to solve this problem like the following code. But this method is really slow and the function `iterrows()` is usually not recommended in pandas and this row will become as

**[UPDATE]**

```
df['before_1hr_mean'] = np.nan
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   df.loc[index, 'before_1hr_mean'] = df[(df['date'] < row['date']) & \
       (df['date'] >= row['date'] - pd.Timedelta(hours=1))]['value'].mean()
```

Is there a better way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Do you realize that your example increments by days... meaning that the results are identical to your original data.  In this example we're taking the mean of one row.

Comment: Also, your code says `df['date'] <= row['date']` implying that you want to include the current row's value in the mean.  But your example calculation, you exclude the current row's value.  This would also imply that your first row's calculation would be null.

Comment: Sorry for my wrong code. I put the equal sign at wrong position. Learn a lot from your code and null or Nan is ok in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the liberty of changing your data to make it all the same day.  It's the only way I could make sense of your question.

```
df.join(
    df.set_index('date').value.rolling('H').mean().rename('before_1hr_mean'),
    on='date'
)

                 date   value  before_1hr_mean
0 2010-01-01 01:23:00    21.2        21.200000
1 2010-01-01 01:33:00    63.4        42.300000
2 2010-01-01 06:02:00    80.6        80.600000
3 2010-01-01 06:05:00    50.1        65.350000
4 2010-01-01 06:20:00   346.5       159.066667
5 2010-01-01 07:44:00   111.8       111.800000
6 2010-01-01 08:00:00   113.1       112.450000
7 2010-01-01 08:22:00    10.6        78.500000
8 2010-01-01 09:00:00   287.2       148.900000
9 2010-01-01 09:14:00  1652.6       650.133333
```

---

If you want to exclude the current row, you have to track the sum and count of the rolling hour and back out what the average is after adjusting for the current value.

```
s = df.set_index('date')
sagg = s.rolling('H').agg(['sum', 'count']).value.rename(columns=str.title)
agged = df.join(sagg, on='date')
agged

                 date   value     Sum  Count
0 2010-01-01 01:23:00    21.2    21.2    1.0
1 2010-01-01 01:33:00    63.4    84.6    2.0
2 2010-01-01 06:02:00    80.6    80.6    1.0
3 2010-01-01 06:05:00    50.1   130.7    2.0
4 2010-01-01 06:20:00   346.5   477.2    3.0
5 2010-01-01 07:44:00   111.8   111.8    1.0
6 2010-01-01 08:00:00   113.1   224.9    2.0
7 2010-01-01 08:22:00    10.6   235.5    3.0
8 2010-01-01 09:00:00   287.2   297.8    2.0
9 2010-01-01 09:14:00  1652.6  1950.4    3.0
```

Then do some math and assign a new column

```
df.assign(before_1hr_mean=agged.eval('(Sum - value) / (Count - 1)'))

                 date   value  before_1hr_mean
0 2010-01-01 01:23:00    21.2              NaN
1 2010-01-01 01:33:00    63.4            21.20
2 2010-01-01 06:02:00    80.6              NaN
3 2010-01-01 06:05:00    50.1            80.60
4 2010-01-01 06:20:00   346.5            65.35
5 2010-01-01 07:44:00   111.8              NaN
6 2010-01-01 08:00:00   113.1           111.80
7 2010-01-01 08:22:00    10.6           112.45
8 2010-01-01 09:00:00   287.2            10.60
9 2010-01-01 09:14:00  1652.6           148.90
```

Notice that you get nulls when there isn't an hours worth of prior data to calculate over.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I know what the OP is asking for, but isn't it a little strange that the "before_1hr_mean" column is exactly the same as the value column?

Comment: That is strange... I didn't even notice that.  Well now that opens a can of worms an ambiguity.  OP needs a better example, or I can decipher what their code is doing.  BTW, their code produces the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I think OP needs to specify why each row is a different _date_ although we're talking about "before 1 hr".

Comment: @DSM let me know if you think this makes sense

Comment: Thanks for your answer!